# Encountering ImportError when trying to import 'BioGptModel' from 'transformers'

Tags: importerror, transformer-model, huggingface

I am working with the `Transformers` library in Python. My goal is to use the `BioGptModel` model. Here's the code I've written:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BioGptModel
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")
model = BioGptModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")

inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)

last_hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

Unfortunately, when I run the code I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'BioGptModel' from 'transformers'", tried all solution upgrade transformer and related libraies but still same error

What am I doing wrong? Is 'BioGptModel' not part of the 'transformers' library, or is there another issue with my code or environment?

Answer (score 0):

BioGPT is part of the transformers library and it is classified as a CausalLM so you want to write:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")
```

The problem is with the import statement. You should import the general class of model and then use the from_pretrained argument for the specific model that you want.
Hope that helps!